# HTML PHP form entry problem with space?

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

Im doing this from my phone so feel free to edit the code for me. Thanks :L

So I have a form, and I'm trying to transfer data FROM a MYSQL database to a hidden field to be submitted in a form. However, I found that if the data in the DB had a space in it (ie Hello there) it only takes "Hello" and skips "there" completly. How would I fix this, and if its not fixable, is there a way around it? Thanks.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ##### ORDER BY `id` DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $test=$row['name'];
  $id=$row['id'];
  echo"<form method=post action=\"joingroup.php\"><input type=hidden name=test value=$test><input type=submit value=\"Submit\"></input></form>";
}
```

ANSWER:
Put \" 's around the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a value with a space in it, you *must* enclose that value within quotes in your HTML:

Try this:

```
echo "<form method=post action=\"joingroup.php\">
        <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"test\" value=\"$test\">
        <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">
      </form>";
```

Or better yet, use single quotes (and concatenation, since PHP variables aren't evaluated within single quotes like they are with double quotes):

```
echo '<form method="post" action="joingroup.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="' . $test . '">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>';
```

Or, for best results, don't `echo` out your HTML. Instead, drop out of PHP and jump back in just long enough to `echo` needed variables:

```
<?php
  // get values from DB, etc.
?>

<form method="post" action="joingroup.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" value="<?php echo $test; ?>">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
  // resume processing here
?>
```

Comment: @Ken Not a problem. Glad I could help. Be sure to read my last update, regarding writing out HTML from outside PHP, as that's the *best* way to do something like this.

Comment: Just curious, why is 'best' proposed? Is it for cleanliness or speed or debugging or future-proofing or....

Answer (score 0):

Check the database fields if they are defined as VARCHAR and see the length of each field. Usually this might be the problem, I cannot think of anything else.

Comment: They are VARCHAR so thats not the problem.

Comment: And what is the length of the field in MySQL? Usually you have to define the length of VARCHAR field like 255 characters for example.

Comment: 40, but "hello there" is not 40 characters.

Comment: Then I don't see any problem except that your HTML input elements should be self closed and the attribute value should be in quotes. <input type="hidden" name="test" value="'.$test.'" /> also for the submit one.